# Create a four dimensional array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create a four-dimensional array using the **line space** method.
For the same, I am trying to find the shape of this array I created using the **line space** from Numpy. During the same, I am receiving an error which is attached below.

**The error is as follows**

```
<ipython-input-6-a26cc4917f44> in <module>
----> 1 big.shape()

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

The code for the same is attached below.

**CODE**

```
import numpy as np
akash = np.linspace(1, 10)
#print(akash)
big = akash
print(big)
```

Comment: Try `big.shape` (not the lack of parentheses). I would recommend going through a numpy tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`numpy.ndarray.shape`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy.ndarray.shape) returns a tuple, and as it's not a function, there's no need to call it with parenthesis.

See the example from the documentation:

```py
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> x.shape
(4,)
>>> y = np.zeros((2, 3, 4))
>>> y.shape
(2, 3, 4)
```